# How to get bounds of UIBezierPath excluding control points

Tags: nsbezierpath

`NSBezierPath` provides an API called `bounds` that returns bounds without control points.
Is there any equivalent API in `UIBezierPath` to return the path bounds excluding control points?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got the solution, which was simple. `CGPath` provides such a call: `CGPathGetPathBoundingBox`. We can always get `CGPath` from `UIBezierPath`.

Answer (score 0):

`UIBezierPath` has `bounds` property. https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibezierpath/1624350-bounds